# AutoComplete="Off" or autocomplete="new-password" is not working

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, autocomplete, passwords

**AutoComplete="Off"** or **autocomplete="new-password"** is not working in chrome and firefox. I referred following link as well as other questions of stack overflow for solutions. But they are not working. Is there any other workarounds?

https://makandracards.com/makandra/24933-chrome-34+-firefox-38+-ie11+-ignore-autocomplete-off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)